# How to present this example concept in UML: Using 2 LCD displays in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, embedded, uml, lcd

I make it a short as possile. I am an embedded software engineer.
I know C and learn modern C++ for embedded, making my own examples.
Also, I want to learn UML.
ChatGPT can't help me out, since it doesn't understand visual language. Maybe ChatGPT 12 in 2049 can do that ;o
My example: I have an NHD128x64 display, it comes with an ST7565p chip. My main goal here is TO LEARN UML.
What I want to achieve:

- Make a good architecture, here specifically, dependency inversion as part of uncle bob's "SOLID".
- Make it possible to use 2 NHD128x64 displays on the same microcontroller
- Re-Use my C-Code, but use C++ whereever the tradeoff "work vs. achievement of better architecture" makes sense.

So, here is the thing:
There are basically 3 classes: the NHD driver class "Driver_nhd1k", the ST7565p driver class "St7565p", the "WhatPin"-class, which use dependency inversion to implement 2 child-classes to access the hardware for 2 displays, using different GPIO's and different SPI-interfaces. (I know I could just use chip select and then both LCD's can use the same pins, but I am doing this to learn soemthing about architecture).

Or, very simple: The hardware abstraction is done via inheritance of the "WhatPin" class, implementing "spi_send" and "gpio_set" stuff.
The st7565p implements "setColumnAddr" and such things.

As a sidenote, the 1k display memory is used by my "Driver_nhd1k" as well as another, a GFX library, which uses "printf" on it and several "fonts" for this.

One last thing: I understand that "putting the runtime together" is kinda "factory" or "builder" pattern. In the diagram given below, this is not explicilty stated, since I don't knw yet how to make sense of UML.

It all works, in C, but as I said I want to make a software architecture in C++, using UML to describe it.

I made a diagram, which imho explains it pretty good ( or goof !? ).

[image]

In UML, I have various diagram types, for example, a class diagram. Or an object diagram. Or a sequence diagram.
None of this give me, afaik, the ability to communicate the above concept usefully.

So, where is this going ? UML should HELP so simplify, and to visualize, but it seems things get overcomplicated with this. I mean, this amount of mess for one simple "dependency inversion"...

Any Idea, suggestion, further reading, whatever, that gives me a path to continue my learning, would be appreciated.

And sorry for the tldr and thank you very much for investing your time :)

Comment: I have never hated anything in coding as much as UML. I guess it helps some people, but not me. I once had to use a product called Borland Together, the idea was that if you updated the code the UML would automatically update, and if you updated the UML the code would also update. Ridiculous.

Comment: Actually your drawing is just blurb. It's a random mix of UMLish shapes but with no meaning. Either you learn how to model with UML or you stay away from it. This way i no use...